# How to detect the loading of the image from the Internet - progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a class:

```
    public class DownloadImageFromInternet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView;

    public DownloadImageFromInternet(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String imageURL = urls[0];
        Bitmap bimage = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            bimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Message", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bimage;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

I want to create a progress bar that will detect the loading of the image I download from the internet.
How to do it?

Comment: Since there are quite a few things to consider when downloading files on Android, you could use the [Downloader Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#AboutLibraries) from Google which provides a lot of functionality (including progress reporting to the UI) out of the box.

Comment: As another suggestion, you can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) from Square. Might match your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it's done:

```
public class DownloadImageFromInternet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    public DownloadImageFromInternet(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(); //Create dialog
        pd.show(); // show dialog
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ...
        ..
        return bimage;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Please tell my what with context in: protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(contex???); //Create dialog
        pd.show(); // show dialog
    }protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(); //Create dialog
        pd.show(); // show dialog
    }

Comment: You need to pass `Context`, just like you passed an `ImageView` into constructor of Async class. `Context` could be the instance of an `Activity` i.e. keyword `this`.